# why do people use .net for web development

Tags: .net

I just want to know why people use dot net over something like php for web dev. What are the advantages? Is it true that .net generates your javascript and html?

Comment: Since I can't answer for real: because of the versatility of .Net.  I develop desktop applications, web applications, mobile applications, Silverlight, etc...all using C# and .Net.  Now that is a powerful platform.

Answer (score 2):

WebForms provides an abstraction of Web development that mimics classic Windows development. plus, the C# and VB.NET can be used to develop desktop programs, and the business object libraries that can be shared between ASP.NET and Desktop applications easily.

I know developers who develop ASP.NET applications with only rudimentary knowledge of CSS/HTML/Javascript, but you cannot completely forgo that knowledge -- an ASP, like  PHP page, is mostly HTML.

Answer (score 2):

I use it because it's really powerful and the IDE (Visual Studio, Intellisense) is amazing. You can do anything from creating a quick app to a full-blown enterprise app relatively easy with a lot of the boring stuff abstracted out. Of course if you like the boring stuff you have the ability to modify it as well.

But I would say that Intellisense is why I use it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use .NET for web programming because of it's powerful framework.  (I.E. all the System.* things.)

You can generate your JS and HTML using WebForms and the WebForms designer, but if you're the person who values [POSH](http://microformats.org/wiki/posh) design techniques, this isn't really an option.

Basically, it just comes down to a matter of opinion, whether you want to use the built-in WebForms and ASP.NET MVC frameworks with .NET, or whether you long for CGI-style PHP or mod_perl scripts.